# Why argparse.py is always run first?

Tags: python-3.x

I write some script file in the folder, and the architecture shows like this
|----argparse.py
|----script_1.py
|____script_2.py

The argparse.py is just a script file which i used to test argparse role.

When I try to run an other script file, the strange thing happened, argparse.py is always the first file to run, not matter which file i choose.
Only when i reanme argparse.py as other file name will it not happend.

Is there anybody know what cased this situation? Thanks.

Comment: do you happen to `import argparse` in the other modules? if yes, then you are shadowing the name of the built-in module.

Comment: something show change line, i just mean some independent script in the same foler and one is named argparse.py

Comment: yes, if you `import argparse` in another script and you have argparse.py in the same folder, Python will import that (and execute all its code) instead of importing the [built-in argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: @JanWilamowski I have just try your comment, it really works. thanks. but why, will python run time scan all files in the same foler when i want to run one script in the folder even if it doesn't import other files?

Comment: It won't scan all files in the folder. But IF you `import argparse` in your script it will look for argparse.py in the folder (actually in the Python import path). After that, it will check built-in modules. That's why I asked whether you have `import argparse` in your other scripts.